# Validation of schema in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I have been trying to implment a validating interceptor in Spring Integration with no luck.  The first part of my configuration looks like this:

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.UriEndpointMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>

                <prop key="http://localhost/ws/CompanyService">SOAPCompanyGateway</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <int-ws:inbound-gateway id="SOAPCompanyGateway"
        request-channel="SOAPCompanyRequestChannel" marshaller="SOAPMarshaller" unmarshaller="SOAPMarshaller"/>

<bean id="validatingInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
    <property name="schema" value="/WEB-INF/classes/schema/v1_1/CompanyService.xsd"/>
    <property name="validateRequest" value="true"/>
    <property name="validateResponse" value="false"/>
</bean>

<bean id="SOAPMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="contextPaths">
            <list>
                <!-- list all schema versions that we wish to accept -->
                <value>com.predictivesolutions.schema.v1_1</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

However its not validating the XML message.  We have this working with normal Spring WS, but I cannot seem to get it working for Integration (which should be the same).

I read that you can use the interceptor to validate the message before unmarshalling, but not sure how to wire it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interest why don't you provide your `interceptor` to the `EndpointMapping`?

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.UriEndpointMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="http://localhost/ws/CompanyService">SOAPCompanyGateway</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptors">
        <array>
            <ref bean="validatingInterceptor"/>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am still new to Spring Integration so I was unaware that I could place that right on the EndpointMapping element.

Comment: One more question, can I route a validation error to a channel?

Comment: Probably with custom `EndpointInterceptor` which extends from that `PayloadValidatingInterceptor`. But it is a new SO question, if you have issues with that.